# Слой активных областей для зданий

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Цитата из документации Яндекса: "Слой активных областей и картиночный слой существуют независимо друг от друга, и порядок их добавления на карту неважен. В некоторых случаях слой активных областей может использоваться и без картиночного (например, если нужно сделать интерактивным изображение какого-то дома на карте)." Теперь, каким образом это реализовать? Имеется массив зданий в виде полигонов (JSON). Переконвертировал географические координаты в пиксельные. Пересоздал файл: обернул json в callback-функцию. Запускаю - и ничего.
Нужно ли разбивать экран на тайлы и создавать набор тайлов для каждого зума? Если да, то как можно узнать количество объектов, попадающих на каждый тайл (объектов много тысяч)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно ли разбивать экран на тайлы и создавать набор тайлов для каждого зума?

Да, нужно. Посмотрите как это реализовано в примере.

https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-examples/tree/ru-v2.1/hotspot_layer/hotspot_data/10

> Если да, то как можно узнать количество объектов, попадающих на каждый тайл (объектов много тысяч)?

Для начала нужно узнать каким координатам соответствует этот тайл. Здесь есть функция решающая обратную задачу https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/dragger . А затем выбрать объекты попадающие в этот файл, если даже они попадают частично. Затем сформировать данные для файла. Это самая быстрая технология, но формирование файлов чрезвычайно трудоемкий процесс.

Имхо, вам стоит приглядеться к ROM https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/ он должен вытягивать такие объёмы, если использовать кластеризацию.

Comment: разве OM поддерживает кластеризацию для полигонов?

Comment: ROM показывает данные так как вы ему вернете, соответственно вы можете кластеризовать полигоны тоже

Comment: Прикольно. Спасибо. Попробую.